# Create PowerShell script file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, webforms, powershell-3.0

I research a lot in last couple days and I found only solutions for execute powershell scripts but I did't find how to create .ps1 file.

I have web app (ASP.NET) and I need to dynamically create/save script without running.

If anyone have some direction please tell me

note. Version of powershell is 3.0, and I included needed dll in project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PowerShell script is nothing more than a text file with a .ps1 extension. Just use StreamWriter to create the file with the commands you want and save with the .ps1 extension.